# Adding bottom arrow/triangle to a hovered active element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<ul>` that is displayed `inline-block` and I need it to have a arrow appear when the element is active, see screenshot:

[image]

And here is what I have currently:

[image]

I already have the functionality with activating the element on hover:

**.coffee**

```
$(".solutions-items li").hover ->
  $(this).addClass("solutions-items-active").siblings().removeClass "solutions-items-active"
```

My **.html**

```
<div class="text-center">
    <ul class="solutions-items">
      <li class="solutions-items-active"><img class="home-solutions-icon" src="" alt="online shop"></li>
      <li><img class="home-solutions-icon" src="" alt="mobile smartphone"></li>
      <li><img class="home-solutions-icon" src="" alt="couch commerce tablet"></li>
      <li><img class="home-solutions-icon" src="" alt="pos point of sale"></li>
      <li><img class="home-solutions-icon" src="" alt="marketplace"></li>
      <li><img class="home-solutions-icon" src="" alt="wearables"></li>
      <li><img class="home-solutions-icon" src="" alt="e-commerce innovations"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And here is my css:

**.scss**

```
.solutions-items li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.home-solutions-icon {
  height: 7em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.solutions-items-active {
  background: $green;
}
```

Any ideas how I can tackle this? Thanks !

Comment: You may want to add more code, and possible include a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Please provide all the relevant HTML, CSS and JavaScript which recreates what you have already achieved in your second image. That way we can use it as a basis for our answers.

Comment: Just so you know, you don't need JS to style the hover states, simply use: .solutions-items li:hover { ... }

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want to add a bit of CSS to do that. If your image has a fixed size, there is a CSS trick to do that :

```
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;

    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
```